# Perform insert for each row taken from a select?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, insert

I have a number of records that I need to insert into multiple tables. Every other column will be a constant.

Poor pseudo code below - this is what I want to do:

```
create table #temp_buildings
(
    building_id varchar(20)
)
insert into #temp_buildings (building_id) VALUES ('11070')
insert into #temp_buildings (building_id) VALUES ('11071')
insert into #temp_buildings (building_id) VALUES ('20570')
insert into #temp_buildings (building_id) VALUES ('21570')
insert into #temp_buildings (building_id) VALUES ('22570')

insert into property.portfolio_property_xref
        ( portfolio_id ,
          building_id ,
          created_date ,
          last_modified_date
        )
values
        ( 
            34 ,
            (
                select  building_id
                from    #temp_buildings
            ) ,
            getdate() ,
            null
        )
```

**Intent:** Perform an insert into property.portfolio_property_xref for each record on #temp_buildings

I think I could do this with a cursor - but believe this would be horribly slow. As this exercise will be repeatable in future I'd rather tackle this in a faster method but I'm unsure how. Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: Tip: You can also use `insert into #temp_buildings (building_id) VALUES ('11070'), ('11071'),...` to insert multiple rows.

Comment: @Habo Nice one - just cut a good 50 rows off my script :) Thank-you

Answer (score 174, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( column1 )
SELECT  col1
FROM    table2
```

Like:

```
insert into property.portfolio_property_xref
( 
    portfolio_id ,
    building_id ,
    created_date ,
    last_modified_date
)
select
    34,
    building_id,
    getdate(),
    null
from
    #temp_buildings
```

Comment: Eck. I'm embarrassed if it's this simple :)

Comment: But there it limit for 1000 rows per `insert into select from`

Comment: @procma I don't think that's true. Do you have any evidence?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, not in table-to-table insert, but deffinitely in let say "manual" batch-to-table insert `INSERT INTO table1 (ID, Col1)
    VALUES (123, 'abc'), (124, 'def'), (125, 'ghi')`, there you can have only 1000 value-groups

Answer (score 13):

You will want to use `INSERT INTO SELECT FROM` (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3e859/2))

```
insert into property.portfolio_property_xref
( 
    portfolio_id ,
    building_id ,
    created_date ,
    last_modified_date
)
SELECT 34 ,
       building_id,
       getdate(),
       null
from    #temp_buildings
```

Answer (score 2):

Kind of random, but I feel this may be useful to anyone who comes here to this question.  Sometimes, i use Microsoft Excel VBA to generate portions of SQL Statements like listed above. I find this very useful when I am in situations where i am doing table construction and data transformation to set up a new job.  this is a really simple example.  It created a link between 2 separate unrelated systems.  Then the link allowed me to build a new table in a warehouse environment that tied 3 unrelated systems together.  Anyway, it allowed me to create > 5000 lines of SQL (for onetime use - and a small part of a much larger ETL task) in seconds.

```
Option Explicit

Dim arow As Integer
Dim acol As Integer
Dim lrow As Integer
Dim IsCellEmpty As String
Dim CustNo As Integer
Dim SkuLevel As Integer


Sub SkuLevelUpdate()

'find end ouf input file
arow = 1
acol = 1

Do
    IsCellEmpty = Cells(arow, acol).Value
    arow = arow + 1
Loop Until IsCellEmpty = ""

lrow = arow - 1

'Write SQL
arow = 2
acol = 5

Do
    CustNo = Cells(arow, 1)
    SkuLevel = Cells(arow, 4)
    Cells(arow, acol) = "INSERT INTO dbo.#TempSkuLevelRelationships (CustNo, SkuLevel) VALUES (" & CustNo & ", " & SkuLevel & ");"
    arow = arow + 1
Loop Until arow = lrow

End Sub
```

Yes, I know all about SQL injection, etc.  I create the spreadsheet(s), I copy/paste the data into larger SQL code for new construction, table modifications, and the like when the data does not currently reside in a SQL table

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you can do it with a cursor. As the other answers show you, you wont have to do it. 
SQL Server is a set based RDMS, it is more capable of processing a set of data, then of processing single lines.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
   insert into property.portfolio_property_xref
   ( 
      portfolio_id ,
      building_id ,
      created_date ,
      last_modified_date
   )
   Select
      34,
      building_id,
      GETDATE(),
      NULL
   From #temp_buildings
```